# Listening for variable value change in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm still in progress of learning JavaScript. I am trying to make a dashboard like web application and I can't decide a best way to listen to state changes and react to it.
I came up with something like this:

```
const onStateChange = () => {
    // Call functions to react to given state's change here
    // Change style
    // Hide/show something
    // etc.
};

const state = {
    $value: false,
    stateChanged() {
        console.log(`State has changed to: ${this.$value}!`);
        onStateChange();
    },
    get value() {
        return this.$value;
    },
    set value(value) {
        this.$value = value;
        this.stateChanged();
    },
};

state.value = true; // State has changed to: true!
state.value = false; // State has changed to: false!
```

My idea is to automatically react to change from (for an example) 'loading = true' to 'loading = false' and handle it with provided function without manually calling it.
Do you think something like this makes sense, has any potential problems and/or do you have any suggestions on how to improve it?

Comment: "Do you think something like this will work...." So does it work when you run it?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It does work as provided in last two comments, but I'm sceptical on is it smart to do it this way, since I haven't seen it being used before

Comment: Yes, this works quite well, it's the main idea behind Vue.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Observable pattern

[Read the theory here](https://www.dofactory.com/javascript/design-patterns/observer)

and you can use already built solutions to this like [RxJS's observer](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observer)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a Javascript framework like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) or [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/). Either of those frameworks make it really simple to just add something like this:

```
<p>The current state is {{stateValue}}.</p>
```